# Using positive look ahead in regex to ignore equal at the end or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex: `(?<=\{\{\s*)[a-z_\.]+(?=\s*\}\}\s*[^\s*=])`;

and it supposed to find all the variables inside (only what inside)`{{ }}` without equal sign after it.

```
  {{user.email}}= "got Ya!";
  {{user.name}} = "got Ya!";
  let secret = {{global.test.secret}}
  let myName = {{global.array}};
  let botName = {{user.name}};
  let email = {{user.email}}
```

so it should match the last four variables inside the curly braces, the issue with the last variable `user.email` if it has nothing after it, it will not match it.
how I can solve this?
the link for the Regexr [here](http://regexr.com/57lqp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<=\{\{)[a-z_\.]+(?=\s*\}\}\s*(?![\s\=]))`

demo [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2JgNe7/1)

Comment: Thanks, using negative lookahead inside positive lookahead is a perfect solution.

Comment: I suggest that you use a space character rather `\s` when you mean to match a space. Here `\s*` will gobble up line terminators, causing a string ending `"... secret}}  \n  =..."` to not match. Consider replacing `\s*(?![\s\=]))` with `(?! *=)` (or perhaps `(?! *=|\})`) Lastly, there are very few characters you need to escape in a character class and they do not include '.' or '='.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
{{([^{}]+)}}(?:(?!=\s*").)*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ECEa23/1/).

---

In `JavaScript` this could be:

```js
let str = `
  {{user.email}}= "got Ya!";
  {{user.name}} = "got Ya!";
  let secret = {{global.test.secret}}
  let myName = {{global.array}};
  let botName = {{user.name}};
  let email = {{user.email}}
`;
  
let pattern = /{{([^{}]+)}}(?:(?!=\s*").)*$/mg;
let m;

do {
    m = pattern.exec(str);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Comment: I want what inside the curly braces only.

Comment: @PrinceAl-harasis: And the solution just gives you exactly that.

Comment: Did you mean the double-quote in `(?:(?!=\s*").)*$` to be `=`? If so, can you not replace that part of the expression with `(?!.*=)`? It may be the OP may be happy with `(?!=\s*=)`, but that’s not clear.